# How to individually update columns in a csv file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to insert (update) values in a csv file whenever my code runs.

Here is my csv file content:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
value1,value2,value3
```

When I run my code, I want to only update rows that col2 equals 'value1'. So, col2 and col3 values will be the only values that I am trying to update. For example it would look like this after I run my script:

```
 col1 | col2 | col3
 value1,new_value2,new_value3
```

Here is my code:

However when I run this code, it gives me an error. Any ideas or suggestion on how to fix this code to run?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to selectively replace values per columns using `pd.where`

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(df['col1'] != 'value1', other='new_value2')
df['col3'] = df['col3'].where(df['col1'] != 'value1', other='new_value3')
```

This produces:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   value1  new_value2  new_value3
```